# Concourse result keeps loading

Tags: docker-compose, concourse

I'm new to concourse and really excited to start working with it but I have a problem running the hello world example described here: https://concourse-ci.org/hello-world.html

I'm running this example on a concourse docker setup described here: https://concourse-ci.org/docker-repository.html.

Everything seems to work just fine but when I want to verify the results of both examples it keeps saying loading: 
[Task result loading (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpUIf.png)

Any idea why this would happen? I'm running docker-compose on Mac OS X (El Capitan) but that shouldn't matter right? Is there some additional configuration that I'm missing?

I also noticed when checking the network trace that the following request doesn't return any value: `/api/v1/builds/<buildnumber>/events`

It keeps saying 'pending'. Is that normal? I assume it isn't but I don't know the cause of this. Is there any logging I can check?

EDIT:

It seems to have something to do with the fact that it isn't running on localhost. When I use port forwarding and open concourse on localhost:8080 the results are shown just fine. Also mapping another hostname to 127.0.0.1 with port forwarding enabled works. So only when I communicate directly with the opened docker ports it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you check that all the repo mirrors and registries are available? Sometimes my local Docker registry fails and Concourse can't check the resources because of that.

Comment: There are no issues with the docker registry.

Comment: I still have this problem. Nobody else is having the same issues? Please help.

Comment: Firstly, try to check whether at least one worker is available for you: `fly -t yourTarget workers`. It should return your at least one worker with few running containers. Secondly, try to check logs from both ATC and the worker. It is pretty easy to do: `docker logs --tail --follow container-hash`, where _container-hash_ is the ID of running ATC/worker container (assuming, you run concourse using docker-compose). You can see the IDs for running containers via `docker ps`. Check logs there, may be you can find something useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much frustration I found out that to cause of this issue was that Sophos Anti-Virus was blocking Concourse server-side events...

https://community.sophos.com/products/free-antivirus-tools-for-desktops/f/sophos-anti-virus-for-mac-home-edition/5750/sophos-av-blocks-server-sent-events-sse-on-mac-os-x-yosemite

Comment: Whow, this still seems to be an actual problem. Adding an exception for my domain in sophos fixed it. Thank you